Is every maximal regular ideal prime?
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. A regular ideal $I\subset A$ is an ideal of $A$ generated by idempotents in $A$. The maximal elements of the family of all proper regular ideal of $A$, ordered by inclusion, is called the maximal regular ideals of $A$.
Is every maximal regular ideal prime? I know one could define a topology on the set of all maximal regular ideals of $A$ in exactly the same way as one defines the prime spectrum: the closed sets has all maximal regular ideals containing some subset of $A$. It would appear to be not natural to me if the topology of maximal regular ideals is not regarded as a subspace of the prime spectrum. If not, is there a more general notion of prime spectrum where one replaces "prime" by some suitable generalization of prime ideals?
